# Better way to add VerticalScroll bar in QTreeWidget which includes another widget in C++

Tags: c++, qt

In my Qt application, I have a Main Window which includes many tab widgets and spin box. I have also added one QTreeWidget inside my MainWindow using QT Designer. Say name of QTreeWidget inside MainWindow is mainWindow_TreeWidget.

Now, I have one more form say TestForm inherited from QWidget, this form have many spin boxes.

Here, I loaded my TestForm which is inherited from QWidget, inside my   MainWindow->mainWindow_TreeWidget(). using below method:

```
TestForm *testForm = new TestForm(ui->mainWindow_TreeWidget);
```

Here: "ui->mainWindow_TreeWidget" becomes tha parent of the TestForm

TestForm constructor:

```
TestForm(QWidget *parent = 0);
```

TestForm was loaded successfully but since the size of the TestForm was bigger than the size of mainWindow_TreeWidget so TestForm was not completely visible.

Than i added QScrollArea inside my TestForm and again loaded in MainWindo mainWindow_TreeWidget and then I can see my TestForm complete using Vertical Scroll bar.

Here, I want to ask :-

1. Is this is a correct way in which I am implementing?
2. Also, since mainWindow_TreeWidget which is inside MainWindow is having VerticalScrollPolicy is "ScrollBarAsNeeded" than why vertical scrollbar didn't came automatically when i loaded the TestForm inside mainWindow_TreeWidget ?

Kindly suggest.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Are you using layouts? Also some pictures may help your question.

Comment: Hello Hayt, Thanks for your reply. I just want to know if I have QTreeWidgetItem inside MainWindow in which VerticalScrollPolicy is set as"ScrollBarAsNeeded"  for QTreeWidgetItem and in that If I load another QWidget (like i mentioned in my query, having size more than the size of QTreeWidgetItem ). Why the vertical scroll bar was not visible ? or is to possible to make VerticalScroll bar visible.

Comment: See here I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995899/add-scrollbar-in-qt-window