# QScrollArea not showing a scrollbar

Tags: qt, qt-designer, qscrollarea

I have a `infoWindow` which is a QWidget, and I can open it by clicking info in the QMainWindow or by the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

`infoWindow` contains vertical layouts holding the videos' metadata, and all the layouts are inside a QScrollArea.

[image]

The problem is, even though the data exceeds the window's max height, which I want to be a static 640x480, there is no scrolling bar showing.

[image]

Comment: [How to add a scrollbar to a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995899/add-scrollbar-in-qt-window?rq=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `QScrollArea` is missing a layout itself (red stop sign on layout icon of tree). The total size of area is tracked by layout. You likely have set fixed or minimal sizes for each panel and add, let's say, vertical layout to `QScrollArea`.